# Ceiling of Long Integer division in c++

Tags: c++, integer, long-integer, ceil

I was trying to solve some problem which involves division of large numbers. I stumbled upon certain scenario where  I'm getting wrong results using:

LL result = (LL)ceil((double)(a-b)/c), where a,b and c are long long integers(LL).

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* ceil */
#define LL long long

int main ()
{
    LL a= 10000000000000000;
    LL aa = 10000000000000000-1;
    LL aaa = 10000000000000000+1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1;
    printf ( "%Ld\n", (LL)ceil((double)(a-b)/c) );
    printf ( "%Ld\n", (LL)ceil((double)(aa-b)/c) );
    printf ( "%Ld\n", (LL)ceil((double)(aaa-b)/c) );
    return 0;
}

Output:
10000000000000000
9999999999999998
10000000000000000
```

This starts to happen to integers which are greater than or equal to 10^16 and is divisible by 10.
The upper bound of long long is ~10^18.
So What is causing this error?

I'm using GCC 5.1 in C++14 mode (on ideone.com).

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: I tried the compliler used by Ideone(C++ 14). Here is the link to the code : http://ideone.com/aT6nem

Comment: Precision of a double is 52-bits = 15 digits.

Comment: @stark If you add this as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it can store numbers with much larger *magnitude*, a typical implementation of `double` can only maintain around 15-16 digits of precision.

Subtraction with floating point can also be something of a problem, especially if the two numbers are of nearly the same magnitude. If both inputs are (say) 50 bits, but the first 40 bits are identical, those will cancel out, and the result will only have about 10 bits.

So, first of all, you probably want to do all the math with `long long` if that's the type you want for the result. Second, you might at least want to consider rearranging your `(a-b)/c` to `a/c-b/c` to delay the subtraction as long as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that both values are positive, you can calculate the ceil in purely integer (or long long) with:

```
    (x + y-1)/y
```

So, in your case:

```
    (a - b + c-1)/c
```

Handling negative numbers is left as an exercise for the reader (it can be a bit fiddly deciding exactly what you want it to do, and you usually don't need it anyway).

Comment: Thanks. Later I move to this only, after figuring out the error.